# Que un checkbox conserve un valor antiguo

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Contenido con estos valores:

```
Schema::create('contenidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Agrupo todas las filas en un vector llamado $contenidos y los uso para un formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
<div>
    <b><i><u>Habilidades requeridas:</u></i></b><br><br>
    @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
        <input type="checkbox" name="capacidad[]" value="{{$contenido->id}}" {{ (is_array(old('capacidad')) and in_array(1, old('capacidad'))) ? ' checked' : '' }}> {{$contenido->nombre}}<br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es que si se produce un error introduciendo los datos del formulario se conserve que iconos estaban marcados, pero me encuentro que cada vez que se reinicia el formulario debido a datos no validados a diferencia de las cajas de texto los checkbox vuelven a estar sin marcar.
¿Como soluciono esto?

Comment: la mejor forma de conserva los checkbox seleccionado seria que lo enviarlo por medio de ajax, eso evitar que recargue la pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar lo siguiente, debería funcionar:

```
<div>
    <b><i><u>Habilidades requeridas:</u></i></b><br><br>
    @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
        <input type="checkbox" name="capacidad[]" value="{{$contenido->id}}" 
        {{ !empty(old('capacidad')) && in_array($contenido->id, old('capacidad')) ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{$contenido->nombre}}<br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\juego\resources\views\formularios\juego_crear.blade.php)

Comment: editado: sobraba un ")"

Comment: Gracias por corregirlo. Ahora si que funciona. Ya me funciona.